# Grout floor then tile walls?

Tags: shower, tile, floor

I've already got the shower floor tiled (4'x8'- half in 2x2 on shower pan and the other half 1'x2' tile).  Im using epoxi grout on the floor, and regular grout of the same color on the walls.  Should i grout the floor first, then tile the walls?  (walls ar 9' high)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If you found the answer good, you can click the checkmark to "accept" it. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 4):

I would work from the top down, leaving the floor for the end to prevent damage to the floor grout.

It should not be a problem standing and working on the ungrouted floor, just make sure the thin-set is cured. Cover it with cardboard or some old carpet or something.

Comment: I want to stress covering the floor, maybe even with 1/4" plywood. Dropping  any tools or tile pieces  on ungrouted tile can crack them very easy, especially  on the corners.

Comment: +1 on what Jimmy Fix-it said. Work from the top down.  Walls first, then the floor.  And I would do what Jack said & put something down over the already installed floor tiles.  Besides the possibility of damage, a tile could be knocked loose if it's not locked in by the adjoining tiles & grout.

Comment: I agree with both Jimmie & jack + @stevesh click on there up arrow and that gives them the + recognition. It can also help the op decide on if it is a good answer, lots of upvotes can help someone that is not sure what to try.